# Creating PDF documentation

Tags: php, codeigniter, dompdf

I'm in the process of building a web application and will need to create documentation on a customer by customer basis. These files will be saved in pdf format.

I'm looking for help in the process and production of these reports, should I use a doc/docx template and load that data into the file then create the pdf (if it is possible), or create the document in html/css and then use dompdf or something similar to create the pdf?

I'm using codeigniter as my framework.

Comment: In the end I used **FPDF** & **FPDI** & extended them. I was happy with the quality of the fonts, printing produced excellent results.

The only issue was the time it took, some pages had to hand coded, instead of being able to use a template or html

Answer (score 2):

Personal preference I guess, but I really like XSLFO and FOP.  http://grover.open2space.com/content/creating-pdf-code-fop

Comment: a year ago i made something like this for the company i was working in... if i only knew this!

Answer (score 1):

[MPDF](http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/) has worked wonders for me. It's an HTML to PDF program. It supports quite a bit of CSS, and I generally found it easy to work with.

My application is creating 100+ page reports with different page layouts/orientations, multiple tables, images, fonts, PDF imports, etc, and the MPDF part works reliably.

Answer (score 0):

Personal experience: I have used [tcpdf](http://www.tcpdf.org/) and was satisfied with the result I got.

Answer (score 0):

I've been finding that the typographic quality of just about any PDF creation library is utterly gutterly. If it's an option at all, you might consider pasting your data into a LaTeX template and running `pdflatex` on that (or `xelatex`) to get a nice-looking, high-quality document.

This will require a certain amount of setup and development on your part, but there's a chance that it'll look infinitely better than any direct PDF creation results.